# Javascript display image on audio current time

Tags: javascript, audio

im just a beginner in javascript and im stuck at a problem.
when i click play with function play()
it shows if its <= 2.5 but not when its > 2.5 .(I displayed the 'reddot' in html as display hidden).

```
function play() {

    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
    if (audio.currentTime <= 2.5) {
        document.getElementById('reddot').style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (audio.currentTime > 2.5) {
        document.getElementById('reddot').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('reddot2').style.display = 'block';
    }

}

function () {

}

function pause(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.pause();


}
function load(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;

}

function rewind() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
    audio.currentTime = (audio.currentTime-6);
}
```

Comment: No matter where the error is, you should replace the `if... if...` structure with an `if... else...` one, since the condition of the second `if` is exactly the opposite of the condition of the first one.

Comment: i already have solved my problem. i did it with jquery